# VBA Access - Application.FileDialog

Tags: vba, ms-access

Quick question, I have a simple bit of code which allows the user to click on a textbox and find the location of the required file. However, can I get this so that when the "Browser" popup appears, is so that it shows a specific file path ie; T:\Production

```
Private Sub SideProfile_Click()

        Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

        With Application.FileDialog(3)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                SideProfile = "#" & vrtSelectedItem & "#"

            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
            End If
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
.InitialFileName = CurrentProject.Path 'Or any path
```

to the `With Application.FileDialog(3)` block.